Can I change indentation when type and name are on different lines?
When I write:
{
    my_type my_name;
}

in C/C++, putting a new line between the type and name is formatted by the = action as follows:
{
    my_type
        my_name;
}

I would prefer if it was formatted as:
{
    my_type
    my_name;
}

How can I achieve this?

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons.  It allow the question to rest :-)

For C/C++ the default indentation strategy is cindent.
It is controlled by a number of parameters, among them: cinioptions.
For you specific desire you can do:
set cinioptions=+0

More information about the possibles value with :help cinoptions-values
More information about the parameters that control the cindent behavior with :help 'cindent'

Setting this option means that, for my_type my_name = my_function(my_args);, putting a new line after the = will not indent my_function, however I would want this to still be indented. Is there any way to have this work as I want, or is this more complicated?

At first glance this is not supported by the cindent indentation of Vim. You can also develop your own indentation method using the indentexpr but for C/C++ it requires effort :-). It is not exactly automatic indentation but you could be interested to use external programs to format your code like clandformat and use the formatprg option.
